# Geolocation has been disabled in this document by feature policy

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, geolocation

We have built a custom viusalforce page (testpage) to fetch and update current geolocation coordinates on the contact object. 
working fine on all the devices, but from the last one week, getting below exception in the Android device(salesforce 1app)

Error Message   : Geolocation has been disabled in this document by feature policy.

Comment: hi @srija, did you find the solution?